# EF-Core - Database first migration

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

I'm wondering if there's a standard way of handling migrations when using EF Core database-first.

Every time I make change to the database I run this in the CLI:

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=myCatalog;Trusted_Connection=true;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o Models -f
```

The problem with it overrides every change I made in other entity and in the dbcontext, for example I have an interface of `Id` for each entity, when I scaffold I later need to add this to the entity again, is it possible sync the project with the database or maybe just the specific entity?

Another problem is that I recently had to change the default`DeleteBehavior` of the entities from `DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull` to `DeleteBehavior.Cascade` so now every time I use the scaffolding approach I need to change manually 100+ entities in the `OnModelCreating` method.

Comment: Actually you can customize your scaffolding by overriding [IDesignTimeServices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/services). You can inject your manual changes into scaffold process.

Answer (score 7):

You don't *really* have database-first in .Net Core. So what that means is that the scaffold command is just there to get you up and running in a code-first project where you have an existing database.

What this means for you is that you have to decide where you're going to be making your changes:

**a) The Database, or**

**b) The Data Access Project**

Either of those options are valid, but you *have* to pick one and stick to it.

If you're making changes in the DB, you will have to ALTER all your tables and add the ID field to them, then run the Scaffold command again to update your model.

If you're making changes to your entities in the DA project, then you have to add an EF Core Migration each time you change a bunch of things.

In both those cases, you want to include the DB updates as part of your deployment, either via a bunch of SQL scripts, or by making the application perform a DB migration on Startup.

But what you should NOT be doing is trying to change things in both places. That's how you break deployments.

Comment: I worked with the way you suggested over a year and now I have a problem, I had to change inside the `OnModelCreating` the default delete behavior of an entity from `DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull` to `DeleteBehavior.Cascade` so every time I use the Scaffolding approach I need to change manually 100+ entities. Is there a way to configure this in the database level?

Comment: Did you create and apply a migration after you made the DeleteBehaviour change?

Comment: On the database side, you can modify the foreign key relationship to be CASCADE or SET NULL, etc. It's pretty easy with SQL Management Studio.

Comment: Hello there. I am facing this dilemma also. In general, which one is preferred?

Comment: Preferred? For new projects definitely code-first. But it really depends on the situation. E.g. if it's not just your project that will connect to the DB and other projects will also require changes to the DB, then DB first is better. If it's a DB to support just your service, then code-first. Code first is also nice in that it makes DB change rollouts pretty easy in the cloud.

Comment: Is your database really simple? If so then code-first may save you time. BUT even though it's now in v5 EF Core is still not fully featured, and if you are getting even slightly complex with your database, or looking to tune it to be fast, let the database be in control of the database, and go database-first. People will say EF and code-first can handle anything, until you bring them a "how do I get EF to.....?" Then it doesn't.

Comment: @CaptainKenpachi I don't know how to perform an initial migration after scaffolding using DB First. Could you please show me?

Comment: YOu can use commands `dotnet ef migrations add myFirstMigration` and `dotnet ef database update`

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can limit which tables are reverse engineered by specifying schemas and tables.

> The `--schema` option can be used to include every table within a schema, while `--table` can be used to include specific tables. **Note :**  Use `--table` for CLI. And `-table` for Package manager console.

Try like below to update only `Foo` table. [Click here for more detail.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#specifying-tables)

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=myCatalog;Trusted_Connection=true;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o Models -f --table Foo
```

Comment: I get : `Unrecognized option '-table'`

Comment: Try with `--table` as mentioned in the [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#specifying-tables). Use `--table` for CLI. And `-table` for `Package manager console`.

Comment: `--table` deletes all the dbcontext except for the specific table.

Comment: Ohh yes, As of now this is all we have. Try with create another `dbcontext`, Merge it to actual `dbcontext`. And made necessary changes to model for respective `table`. This way you will only need to perform rework for single `entity` instead of `all`.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is very late after initial post, however, I faced a situation where I had to take over a system that is 15 years old. I wanted to create an API for the system, and make use of EF. What I've done is I used `scaffold` to create the models and Entity configurations. I then created a migration from that and in the DB added the Migration entry into the `__EFMigrationsHistory` table. If the table does not exist, you can do an `Update-Database` which will produce an error because the tables already exist, but it creates that table in the DB. From there I was able to create additional migrations for my table changes that I want to make. Then I canuse the old structures as well.